# Microsoft Word Table Cell Top Margin - applying different top margin to different cells in the row

Tags: microsoft-word, margins

I have a table in MS Word.  As you can see I have specified varying top margin to the cells in the first row, however it seems that the largest cell top margin is applied to all cells in the row.  Why is this and is there any way to achieve different cell top margins for different cells in the same row?

[image: Top Margin Example Table]

Note that the cells are all aligned to the top, so my expectation would be that the three screenshots would appear at different heights.

Comment: That is not possible in Word. Can having different top-border height for all three cells work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, you cannot have different margins. However, you can work with merged cells and invisible cells to obtain a visibly identical result.

1) Draw a table with two extra-rows at the top. Then start to merge the cells, as on the picture
[image: merging table cells]

2) Set all table borders to 'no border', then with the 'Border Painter' tool, draw the cell borders that you need. Make sure that in the 'Layout' tab, 'View Gridlines' is selected (see third photo), otherwise you won't see the invisible table lines 
[image: drawing the table borders]

3) Finished result. Note that you can set the height of the invisible cells through the ruler on the left-hand side. If you toggle 'View Gridlines' you can turn on and off the visibility of hidden cell borders. In any case, the hidden cell borders will not print. 
[image: end result of three different 'margins']

Proceeding with these tools, you can create almost any custom design. This is the main advantage over other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don’t think your needs can be fulfilled.

A row of cells in the same table will have the same height, you can only set their different widths.

(If a row of cells in a table has different heights, they also don't look like a table.)

As a workaround, you can insert three different tables,but parallel tables cannot be inserted in word.

You should create three tables in different locations and then manually drag and drop them.

Comment: I'm not looking for different cell height, I'm looking for different cell top margin/padding.

Answer (score 0):

As Binggo pointed out, you can't achieve exactly what you want using cell margins. However, you may be able to fake it, by setting the "before" paragraph spacing for each cell to different values:

[image]

1st and last cells in row 1 are set to 0 pts before, 2nd cell 12 pts, 3rd cell 6pts, and 4th cell 18 pts. Depending on your cell contents, this may get you where you want to be.